# List name javascript click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the category clickable where it spits out a random object from the `activities` it is linked to. For example: click `Winter Activities` and it randomly picks a name from the `Winter Activities` `activities` and changes with each click.

Here is some of the code:

```
var categoryList = document.querySelector('#categories');

for (var i = 0; i < activitiesArray.sections.length; i++) {
    categoryList.innerHTML += "<li><span>" + 
activitiesArray.sections[i].category + "</span></li>";
}

--
var activitiesArray = {
    sections : [
    {
        category: "Winter Activities",
        activities: [
            "Snowboarding", "Snowmobiling", "Ice Skating", "Snow Tubing", "Figure Skating", "Sledding", "Luge", "Bobsleigh", "Polar Plunge", "Ice Fishing", "Skiing"
        ]
    },
    {
        category: "Music",
        activities: [
            "Music Festival", "Concert", "Live Music", "Opera", "Symphony", "Jam Session", "Learn an Instrument", "Musical Theatre"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error messages? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Hi what are you trying to solve? Can you please elaborate more on the question I am happy to help!

Comment: I have a <li> of the `category` names and want to make it where each `category` you click will generate a random `activities` name associated with that `category.

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? That's not how SO works, you have to give it a try, if you can't get it to work, you specify exactly what it is you can't get to work. Don't just ask for others to finish coding for you.

Comment: I'm asking for help on how to do it. The only way I had it working was a button with an `onclick`, but now that I have everything categorized and the categories in a list, I'm not sure how to set it up to only pull the `activities` from the specific `category`

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number based on length of category

```
var categoryList = document.querySelector('#categories'),
    len = activitiesArray.sections.length,
    activities,
    sections,
    activitiesItem;
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sections = activitiesArray.sections[i];
    activities = sections.activities;
    activitiesItem = getRandomInt(activities.length);
    categoryList.innerHTML += "<li><span>" + activities[activitiesItem] + "</span></li>";
    categoryList.innerHTML += "<li><span>" + sections.category + "</span></li>";
}
```

Comment: That seemed to list the activities with the categories. I'll have a separate spot for (one) activity to be appended when you click the category name

Comment: I know I'm probably not being super clear, but I'm trying! lol

Comment: put inside the for loop